# How to use a single instant of a node chat server as a mutitenant for different organisations using that application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, webserver

I have made a node application for customer service support. I want to discuss the FOLLOWING SCENARIO:-

Suppose multiple organisations subscribe for my customer support service (chat service). Now for all teh clients i want to use same backend. Currently for a single organisation, application is working. Suppose a customer comes to site abc.com, then agents of abc.com are able to serve the chats passed to them through node application. I give them script like

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://chatting.com/?initialScript?organisation=abc'
```

through which "chat with us" div is included in their site and all the chat traffic flows to chatting.com(hypothetical name) irrespective of abc.com working. chatting.com keeps track of user with the help of cookies stored in browser (third party cookie). Next time any hit is made to chatting.com that cookie is sent along with the request.

But real problem comes when i want to make this application multitenant. Now suppose abc.com and def.com have subscribed for my application. And a user opens both the sites in a browser side by side in different tabs. Now as my application was saving chatting.com cookies as third party cookies, so both abc.com and def.com "chat with us" option will use same cookie in the browser present against chatting.com. But that will cause conflict as cookie data is same for both the customers. At backend server will treat both the customers as same as they are being differentiated with cookie and cookie is same in both the cases. So that will cause problem.

Now i have thought of one solution. I m using express as backend web server. I will overwrite the default behaviour of express of sending the cookie in each http response. But will send the cookie in javascript file (one used to make "chat with us" div) which will write the cookies on client side using document.cookie javascript function. As a result my application cookies will become first party cookies. Hence next time request is sent to chatting.com, then i will read that cookies from domain of abc.com  by using same document.cookie, and hence cookies will not conflict.

But i m finding this solution lenghty. If anybody has any idea how to accomplish my goal, i ll be thankful for that.

Thanks in advance